# How to enable/disble vibration feedback in Unity?

Tags: unity, ios

I want to create toggle that enable/disable vibration feedback on the device, as i can't figure it out.

How do i do that?

```
public void ToggleVibration()
{
       //enable and disable vibration feedback..
}
```

I want to make a setting (toggle) that user want to use vibration in the game or not, as `Handled.vibrate()` makes the device vibrate only?

Comment: Have you read the docs on [Handheld.Vibrate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.Vibrate.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it only allows to vibrate the device only.

Comment: ...as opposed to vibrating what other thing? Please update your question to include more description of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can turn off the vibration feature of the device. Your game will not vibrate the device unless you call `Handheld.Vibrate()`, so in your Toggle function why not just set a bool to true or false and do a check against that bool when you want to vibrate. You can actually implement a Toggle control from `UnityEngine.UI` and use its OnValueChanged to set the bool.